# Multiple log files in Apache using one configuration file

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, logfile, apache-config

Hi i am working on PHP application in ubuntu and also using log files in log folder and using Apache2

I have 2 sites

1 : **site-1**

2 : **site-2**

> Both are configured in one apache configuration file "ui.conf" which
>   is currently in sites-enable directory

**Example /etc/apache2/sites-enable/ui.conf**

both have their own log file

1: Site-1 = apache_error.log
2: Site-2 = error.log

**The Question is**
How can i manage both site's log files in one apache2 conf file

My current code in ui.conf for managing log file is below:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/home/user1/site1/" fw_log=1

 ErrorLog /home/user1/site1/logs/apache_error.log
 CustomLog /home/user1/site1/logs/apache_access.log combined

 SetEnvIf Request_URI "/home/user1/site2/" qt_log=2

 ErrorLog /home/user1/site2/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /home/user1/site2/logs/access.log combined
```

Comment: I don't get what the question/problem is here, you already manage both site's log files in one Apache2 conf file. Why is this tagged with `PHP`?

Comment: Actually it's a php application both sites are in php, The problem is related to Apache config, i want to manage log files in single apache config. The method which i am using is above but its not working fine. Both site's error are displaying in /home/user1/site2/logs/error.log in the above case.

Comment: None of that code is PHP though. Do you have two vhosts setup for your two sites?

Comment: No i have only one VirtualHost in my ui.conf. I am using different Directories in my vhost

Example :

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     #ServerName firewall
     ServerName ui

     DirectoryIndex index.php
     DocumentRoot /home/user1/

     SSLEngine On
      <Directory>

      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


Have to 2 directories in my ui.conf and each directory has its own log folder and error.log file
which i have to manage in one vhost.

Comment: One vhost -> one log. Seperate them to have one vhost for each of your sites. You can then set a seperate log file for each vhost